# PrimeNG Quill editor max length

Tags: angular, primeng, quill

I'm trying to implement max length for the editor. My code is like this:

```ts
this.editorTextChange$$ = this.quillEditor.onTextChange.asObservable()
  .subscribe((ev) => {
    const limit = this.maxLength;
    // last char is \n, so don't count it
    if (ev.textValue.length > limit) {
      this.quillEditor.quill.deleteText(limit, ev.textValue.length);
    }
    // last char is \n, so don't count it
    this.currentLength = this.quillEditor.quill.getLength() - 1;
  });
```

```html
<p-editor
    #quill
    [(ngModel)] = htmlValue>
    <p-header>
      <span>
        <button title="Bold" class = "ql-bold"></button>
        <button title="Italic" class = "ql-italic"></button>
        <button title="Underline" class = "ql-underline"></button>
        <button title="Link" class = "ql-link"></button>
      </span>
    </p-header>
  </p-editor>
```

The thing is editor gets updated on the view but the model remains the same.

How can I update that?

Thanks!

Comment: We finally decided that the function would be of no use after updating product specs but I still think it could be important to someone who wants to update the text from the controller

Answer (score 0):

After `this.quillEditor.quill.deleteText(limit, ev.textValue.length);`, 
add below code

`this.quillEditor.onModelChange(this.quillEditor.root.innerHTML);
 this.quillEditor..onModelTouched();`